# PHP Mongo Update Specific Fields of a single entry on clicking Submit button

Tags: php, html, mongodb, php-mongodb

I have an HTML table that displays data from MongoDB. However in the final column of each row there is an input form from user that can update the entries of that row.
On clicking the submit, and using `update()` those fields for all the rows are getting edited.

My initial DB entry looks like this :

> {"group_size" : "3", "form" : "tour_request_quote_form", "phone" : "9999999999", "url" : "#", "referrer" : "#", "base_url" : "#", "headers" : { "User-Agent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Safari/537.36" }, "tour_date" : "04-24-2019", "email" : "a@gmail.com", "company_list" : [ "A", "B", "C" ], "person_list" : [ "A", "B", "C" ], "lead_status" : [ "Follow Up", "New Lead", "Booked" ], "lead_assigned" :"NIL", "person_assigned": "NIL", "status":"New Lead"}

The final 3 entries "lead_assigned",  "person_assigned", "status" are editable.

This is the code for my table, the table is displayed perfectly as it should.

```
db=$m->selectDB('fullstack');
$collection = $db->clients;
$cursor = $collection->find();
foreach($cursor as $document){
  if(!(isNull($document["group_size"]) || isNull($document["phone"])|| isNull($document["tour_date"]) || isNull($document["email"])))
  {?>
<tr>
  <td><?php echo $document["group_size"]?></td>
  <td><?php echo $document["form"]?></td>
  <td><?php echo $document["phone"]?></td>
  <td><?php echo $document["tour_date"]?></td>
  <td><?php echo $document["email"]?></td>
  <td><?php echo $document["url"]?></td>
  <td><?php echo $document["referrer"]?></td>
  <td><?php echo $document["base_url"]?></td>
  <td><?php echo $document["lead_assigned"]?></td>
  <td><?php echo $document["person_assigned"]?></td>
  <td><?php echo $document["status"]?></td>
  <td>
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
      <h4>Lead Assignment</h4>
      <select class="lead" name="lead">
        <?php foreach($document["company_list"] as $val) {
          ?>
          <option value='<?php echo $val;?>'><?php echo $val; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
      </select><br><h4>Person Assignment</h4>
      <select class="person" name="person">
        <?php foreach($document["person_list"] as $val) {
          ?>
          <option value='<?php echo $val;?>'><?php echo $val; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
      </select><br>
      <h4>Lead Status</h4>
      <select class="status" name="status">
        <?php foreach($document["lead_status"] as $val) {
          ?>
          <option value='<?php echo $val;?>'><?php echo $val; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
      </select><br><br>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update Details">
    </form>
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
      $document['lead_assigned']=$_POST['lead'];
      $document['person_assigned']=$_POST['person'];
      $document['status']=$_POST['status'];

      updateDB($collection,$document,$document['_id']);
    }
```

This is the updateDB function:

```
function updateDB($collection,$new_data,$id)
{
  $filter=array('_id' => $id,'phone' => $new_data['phone'] );
  $collection->update($filter, array('$set' => $new_data),array('upsert' => true));
}
```

What I want is that the entry with id x,should only get edited with the new values.
However finally this is what's happening

> { "_id" : ObjectId("5cc0dab44b24f233684908fa"), "group_size" : "3", "form" : "tour_request_quote_form", "phone" : "9999999999", "url" : "#", "referrer" : "#", "base_url" : "#", "headers" : { "User-Agent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Safari/537.36" }, "tour_date" : "04-24-2019", "email" : "a@gmail.com", "company_list" : [ "A", "B", "C" ], "person_list" : [ "A", "B", "C" ], "lead_status" : [ "Follow Up", "New Lead", "Booked" ], "lead_assigned" : "A", "person_assigned" : "A", "status" : "Booked" }
>
> { "_id" : ObjectId("5cc0dac94b24f233684908fb"), "group_size" : "4", "form" : "tour_request_quote_form", "phone" : "9099090999", "url" : "#", "referrer" : "#", "base_url" : "#", "headers" : { "User-Agent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Safari/537.36" }, "tour_date" : "05-26-2019", "email" : "ab@gmail.com", "company_list" : [ "A", "B", "C" ], "person_list" : [ "A", "B", "C" ], "lead_status" : [ "Follow Up", "New Lead", "Booked" ], "lead_assigned" : "A", "person_assigned" : "A", "status" : "Booked" }

Both the dummy entries got edited on clicking one submit in the first row, last column.

Comment: The phone is different on the two entries, so they are not the same. As is the `_id` for that matter. It's possible for an `upsert` to result in a new document being created  if you sent something like `phone` only in the predicate. But with the `_id` included this would simply throw a duplicate key error where the `phone` was changed. So the "duplicate" (but they actually are not) entries have not been created by this code. You probably have something else which is responsible, but it's not this code. Also `update()` is deprecated. Please use `updateOne()` where you mean **one** instead.

Comment: I tried using `updateOne()` it resulted in this error, `Call to undefined method MongoCollection::updateOne()`
I am using PHP-Mongo 1.6.8 on XAMPP for Windows 5.5.38

Comment: You *should* be using the modern [PHP Library install](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/current/) and you probably only have the core library ( normally installed from PECL, for non-XAMPP users ). That's the actual standard API for you application to use. Note however that `updateOne()` alone does not "fix the issue". What I'm telling you is the code in your question is **not the cause of the issue**.

Comment: I realized the problem, since there are multiple submit buttons, on clicking even one all are being set since they are printed in a loop and have same name. Got to find a workaround for this.

Comment: Issue resolved, I changed the form name's for each row with "phone" and it's working. Also added a refresh after each submit click.